# How is my Mac Mini and Windows PC communicating?

Tags: networking

So I just bought a Mac Mini that I am using as a build server for developing iPhone apps. My I plugged the Mac Mini in, connected it to my Wifi Router, installed a third party piece of software, called Xamarin on my PC and my Mac Mini and the devices are able to talk to each other.

The Mac Mini is paired to the PC via the Xamarin software BUT somehow the Mac Mini and the PC found each other such this is a network question.

Do two devices, connecting to a home Wifi router for internet, automatically become available on a network, I guessing the Wifi router automatically assigns a 192.168.1.X IP address to each device but I didn't think the Wifi router automatically facilitated a network between two WiFi connected devices.

Since I am new to Apple products, I do not know if the Mac Mini has some BlueTooth or other wireless magic that is making my Pc and Mac Mini be able to find each other or if they are finding each other simply because they are both connected to the same WiFi router?

Comment: They likely use some sort of mDNS/bonjour to find each other.

Answer (score 1):

If your wifi router doesn't support (or isn't configured with) client isolation, then two wifi clients are just on the same network, as if they were plugged into the same LAN.